# How to define default value doctrine entity?

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

I have two tables: `plans` and `marks`.

For this two tables

```
<?php
/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="marks")
 */
class Mark{

    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Plan", inversedBy="marks")
     * @JoinColumn(name="plan_id", referencedColumnName="id")
      **/
    protected $plan = null;
    ...
}
```

And

```
<?php
/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="plans")
 */
class Plan{

     /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Mark", mappedBy="plan")
     */
     private $marks;
     ...
}
```

As you can understand from this code in table `marks` I have field `plan_id` (which store plan id). This field is not mandatory and I want by default that `plan_id = 0`, but I can do it. If I set field `$plan` in class `Mark` = 0, I have error that was expected object. But If I set plan = 0, it save `NULL` in the database, I don't want it at all.

Maybe somebody has some advices?

Answer (score 0):

Use [lifecycle callbacks](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#lifecycle-callbacks) on Mark->setPlan()

```
/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="marks")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Mark{

    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Plan", inversedBy="marks")
     * @JoinColumn(name="plan_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     **/
    protected $plan = null;

   /**
    * @ORM\PrePersist
    * @ORM\PreUpdate
    */    
   public function setPlan(Plan $plan = null){
      if(is_null($var)){
        $this->plan = 0;
      }
   }
```

But I think that Doctrine will return errors trying to find a plan with id = 0.

Comment: No, unfortunately it doesn't work. I see an error `spl_object_hash() expects parameter 1 to be object, integer given`

Comment: That's it, for Doctrine 0 is not NULL